# Abstract Class Error, see declaration of " " is abstract

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I'm been getting this error and I'm not sure how to fix it, `#include "stdafx.h"`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Puzzle {
public:
virtual bool action(char [][8], int, int) = 0;
virtual void print_solution(char [][8], int) = 0;
};

class Queen8: public Puzzle {
public:
bool action(char Q[][8], int row, int col) {
    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        if (Q[r][col] == '1') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for (int r = row, c = col; r >= 0 && c >= 0; r--, c--) {
        if (Q[r][c] == '1') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for (int r = row, c = col; r >= 0 && c < 8; r--, c++) {
        if (Q[r][c] == '1') {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
  }

  void print_solution(char Q[][8], int row) {
    if (row == 8)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++)
                cout << Q[r][c] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }
    for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
        if (action(Q, row, c)) {
            Q[row][c] = '1';
            print_solution(Q, row + 1);
            Q[row][c] = '0';
        }
    }
}
};



int main() {
Puzzle Queen8;
char Q[8][8];
for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
        Q[r][c] = '0';
    }
}
Queen8.print_solution(Q, 0);

}
```

The exact error is:

> c:\users\delta\onedrive\documents\visual studio 
>   2013\projects\consoleapplication46\consoleapplication46\consoleapplication46.cpp(60):
>   error C2259: 'Puzzle' : cannot instantiate abstract class
>
> 1>          due to following members:
>
> 1>          'bool Puzzle::action(char [][8],int,int)' : is abstract
>
> 1>          c:\users\delta\onedrive\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\consoleapplication46\consoleapplication46\consoleapplication46.cpp(9)
>   : see declaration of 'Puzzle::action'
>
> 1>          'void Puzzle::print_solution(char [][8],int)' : is
>   abstract
>
> 1>          c:\users\delta\onedrive\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\consoleapplication46\consoleapplication46\consoleapplication46.cpp(10)
>   : see declaration of 'Puzzle::print_solution'

Comment: read on what an abstract class is in C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `main()` function you are instantiating the `Puzzle` class, not the `Queen8` class:

```
Puzzle Queen8;
```

You should instantiate the `Queen8` instead:

```
Queen8 q;
...
q.print_solution(Q, 0);
```

Besides that, you should always use the `override` keyword when you override virtual functions (C++11 and beyond). This will tell the compiler your intention and it will give you much better warnings and errors in case you miss anything. So inside the `Queen8` class, you should have:

```
bool action(char Q[][8], int row, int col) override {
    ...
}

void print_solution(char Q[][8], int row) override {
    ...
}
```